# How to work with TensorFlow 3d deconvolution?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I have the following 3d transpose operation:

```
    kernel_3d_11 = np.random.rand(3, 3, 3, feature_size*4, feature_size*2)
    cost_volume = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(cost_volume, kernel_3d_11, kernel_3d_11.shape, strides=[1,2,2,2,1], padding="SAME")
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Conv3DBackpropInputOp: input and out_backprop must have the same batch size. Input batch: 3, outbackprop batch: 2, batch_dim: 0 [Op:Conv3DBackpropInputV2]
```

Where the original shape of cost volume is (2, 12, 39, 1, 128).
What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this? I'm not aware of what input batch and output batch the error message is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Given  `feature_size = 64`, your cost volume

```
cost_volume = np.random.rand(2, 12, 39, 1, 128)
```

, `strides = [1,2,2,2,1]` and kernel `kernel_3d_11 = np.random.rand(3, 3, 3, feature_size*4, feature_size*2)`

your output shape will be stretched by 2 and since the number of output features is double the input channels, the output shape tensor should be:

```
output_shape = tf.Variable([2, 24, 78, 2, 256], dtype=tf.int32)
```

Therefore, the transposed convolutional layer will be :

```
output_volume = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(cost_volume,kernel_3d_11, output_shape, strides=[1,2,2,2,1], padding="SAME")
```